# Don't show pagination if only one page is returned (Php)

Tags: php, pagination

I have a simple and working php pagination. If only one page is returned, the pagination still shows up with a link to page one. How do I hide or remove this link of no use when only one page is returned? Any help much appreciated…

My code is like this:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
include 'opendb.php';
?>

<?php
    $row=$conn;
    mysql_select_db('DB_NAME',$row);

    $start=0;
    $limit=12;

    if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        $id=$_GET['id'];
        $start=($id-1)*$limit;
    }

    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT $start, $limit");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))

    {

?>

    <!-- RESULT FROM DB -->

<?  }  ?>


<?php                   
    $rows=$conn;
    mysql_select_db('DB_NAME',$rows);

    $rows=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`"));
    $total=ceil($rows/$limit);

    for($i=1;$i<=$total;$i++)
    {
    if($i==$id) {
?>

        <li class='active'><a href='#'><?php echo "$i"; ?></a></li>

<?php } else { ?>

        <li><a href='<?php echo "?id=$i"; ?>'><?php echo "$i"; ?></a></li> 

<?php }

      }
?>
```

Comment: Can't you just add a `if` statement before your `for` loop to check if `$total > 1`?

Comment: Thanks Cactus - you're right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//check if the qty is greater than one before running the for loop.
if( $total > 1 )
{
   for($i=1;$i<=$total;$i++)
   {
     if($i==$id) 
     {
        echo "<li class='active'><a href='#'>$i</a></li>";
     } 
     else 
     {
        echo "<li><a href='?id=$i'>$i</a></li>";
     }
   }
}
```

Just check the qty before running the loop.

Also your sql syntax is outdated: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Thanks John for showing me exactly where to put the if statement and for warning me of a syntax soon gone

Comment: Welcome.. http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/285929-pdo-in-a-php-class/#entry1467894  for the mysql stuff